# Haze in Arizona / Grand Canyon that gets more apparent around noon - smog or something else?

Tags: meteorology, air-pollution

I just came back from the Grand Canyon, and it's awesome.

However, my friend and I did notice something - it seems that there's some kind of haze in the far horizon that seems worse as the sun rises to noon.

One interesting bit is that a polarizer can clean it up when we take photos, so that suggests it's reflected light.

Regardless, I'm curious, is that just pollution blown into the area? or some other atmospheric feature that I didn't know about

Comment: https://www.pri.org/stories/2016-04-16/fighting-haze-grand-canyon

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus Interesting. Though I've seen similar haze in Utah and California. I guess it's probably pollution?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the haze I've seen in AZ is blown dust. If it's windy and hazy, it's probably dust. There is little moisture/humidity to create haze. Pollution is also a possibility. It would have to travel from somewhere else as there isn't a lot of civilization in that area.